# Check network connection in both Windows ce (PDA) and Desktop

Tags: c#, windows, windows-ce, pocketpc

I am developing a PDA Application using c#,i need's to check internet connection before application starts execute,i have used the following code,which is working fine PDA system but not in Desktop

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            string hosname = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ent = Dns.GetHostEntry(hosname);
            string ip = ent.AddressList[0].ToString();
            bool ret = (ip != "127.0.0.1" && ip != "::1");
            //MessageBox.Show(ret.ToString());
            if (ret)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("internet connected");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("internet not connected");

            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("internet not connected catch");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

when I try to execute the same exe in desktop which is throwing me "internet not connected",where i am going wrong?

Comment: What you are doing is no check for internet but just some (local) name resolution. Whether its results coincidentally match with the presence of an internet connection is, err..., coincidental.
If you don't want to wrestle with OS-dependant queries regarding the status of network interfaces and whether these interfaces only connect to private/local networks, try accessing a commonly available internet service such as www.google.com (choose a web site that most likely is not blocked in some countries) and check whether this access succeeds.

Comment: Thanks elgonzo!sorry for telling this,how should i do this?i mean where exactly i need to change in code?because i am very fresh to c#.

Comment: Maybe `ent.AddressList` is in a different order on your desktop. What's actually in the collection?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, IP addresses or name resolution are not going to tell you whether internet is working or not (either of the two can be set locally, coming from a local domain/DNS/DHCP server or router while an internet connection might not be present...)

Comment: Use **[WebClient.DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx)** (or some other method of WebClient), or use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx). Note, that when you use **WebClient.DownloadData**, it will only fetch the main/core HTML document (or another HTTP response coming from the server), but no auxiliary files like images. Hence, impact on performance of computer and bandwidth of network should be negligible.

Comment: Whether you use the one or the other class depends on the platforms your program must run. While WebClient supports the (older) .NET client profiles and .NET 2.0, HttpClient supports Windows 8 Phone and Windows Store Apps, for example.

Comment: @elgonzo, I agree completely, but as far as the code's concerned, that's most likely the reason why there's a difference between the results. I'm not interested in questioning the validity of the approach, particularly since you already addressed it in your comment!

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, okay, i agree with you, too. Sorry for my little rant. :-)

Comment: Apropos: If you worry about data volume when using it on very slow mobile connections, here some current figures: fetching `http://www.google.com/search?strip=1&q=cache:www.google.com` will result in transmission of ca. 6KB of uncompressed data (if data is sent by the server in compressed form, the transfer amount will be somewhat smaller, ofcourse). In comparison, fetching `http://www.google.com` will result in about 37KB of uncompressed data sent.

Comment: If you got your program working, and you have spare mental capacity you can think about choosing a solution that possibly has less latency and less traffic involved, for example querying NTP servers provided by the "NTP pool project". Still, it would be wise to keep the HTTP approach as fallback in case NTP datagrams are not routed in some networks.

Comment: Just because a network connection is available at the time that you perform this check doesn't, in any way, mean that any actual network usage is going to succeed. Networks *change* constantly. You need to write code that can deal with the network dropping part-way through any given use of the network. Given that you need to write that code anyway, there is **no** point in doing anything beforehand to "check" the network.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ping google for example if a reply that means you have internet. What you've written is just checking if the device has ip address.